# Diagonalization problem in terms of direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In section 8 of "Linear Algebra and Geometry", Kostrikin says that we are going to study the problem of taking a matrix associated with a linear map $f\colon L\to M$ and putting it in its "simplest form" using appropriate bases. Then he says that in "direct sum language", the problem is formulated in the following way:

"Let us construct the exterior direct sum of spaces $L\bigoplus M$ and associate with the mapping f its graph $\Gamma_{f}$: the set of all vectors $(l, f(l)$ in the sum. Its easy to verify that it is a subspace of the sum. We are interested in the invariants of the arrangement of $\Gamma_{f}$ in $L\bigoplus M$."

Can someone explain this analogy more clearly? I don't get what is meant with "invariants" and "arrangement" in this context. Thanks.

Comment: definition of this graph as a subspace of $L \bigoplus M$ doesn'r depend of choosing basis of this space ?

Comment: I don't think so. Why you say that?